# swt: how to leave space on the side?

Tags: java, layout, swt, form-layout

I'm designing an application and I want to set a space on the side. My problem now is, I'm using the FormLayout, and the FormAttachment can only define the percentage of the layout; so whenever the editor get wider(i have scrolledComposite in the background), the side space gets wider too, in which I hope it can remain as a same size. Does anyone has idea about how to solve this problem? thanks in advanced.

```
    FormData data = new FormData();
    data.left = new FormAttachment(5);
    data.top = new FormAttachment(5);
    data.right = new FormAttachment(95);
    Label1.setLayoutData(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an `offset` value on the `FormAttachment` to specify the number of pixels to offset the attachment, so:

```
data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 50);

data.right = new FormAttachment(100, -50);
```

positions at the left and right with a fixed 50 pixel offset.

Comment: thank you so much, I always confused about how to use the offset here.